# $.ajax works, $http does not (status 0; CORS?)

Tags: angularjs, http

I have a cloud service I am attempting to download data from. I can use jQuery's `$.ajax` function to obtain this data with no issue - all status codes expected are returned.

AngularJS is a different story and I have no idea why. I am using the $http service to `get(...)` my data. I know there are a few errors the $http is likely to fail on (a 404 if the user mistypes something in the registration box, or a 403 if they are not authenticated).

Yet, no matter what I attempt - I receive a `status: 0` response everytime and this is pretty useless as you can imagine.

I have a basic function as follows:

```
function get(config) {
    $ionicLoading.show();

    return $http(config)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data.data;
        },
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            throw 'Connection error';
        })
        .finally(function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    );
}
```

I use this to test the connection of one of my cloud services.

Which is fine; however - if I pass it an incorrect subdomain for my service, e.g. incorrect.myservice.com - I receive the following error:

```
GET https://incorrect.myservice.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Which is good - that should result in a 404 error(?).

But, the data returned in the error callback is:

```
Object {data: "", status: 0, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

Which is bad - it should not be 0? It should be 404. I done some research, and it appears that CORS is a bit of a headache in AngularJS $http.

However, from what I have read - it appears that CORS is enabled on my server because looking at the response in Fiddler/Chrome/IE etc., all responses are returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` which is what is required for CORS.

[image: response header]

So I am completely lost on how to further debug this, as I require this functionality in my application. But $http does not appear to be behaving how it should be?

Please can somebody assist and provide a pointer.

All error codes are returning with status: 0 and I have *no* idea why?

Comment: Why would it return a 404? A 404 is returned when the server responds a 404, because the resource doesn't exist on the server. Here, you're trying to send a request to a server that doesn't exist. So you can't get any response, since the request can't even be sent.

Answer (score 3):

> GET https://incorrect.myservice.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>   Which is good - that should result in a 404 error(?).

Nope. If you can't resolve the host name to an IP address, you can't make a TCP connection to it, so you can't even send the HTTP GET, and if you can't send the request, you can't get the response, which is where the 404 would come from. This is a lower level networking error and you don't even get to do any HTTP, so you get no HTTP status code.

This is also not a CORS error. The browser (at least Chrome) will print a really clear and explicit error message if anything goes wrong with CORS.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Any idea how to diagnose? Because I am really scratching my head. I thought status 0 was an "offline" status?

Comment: There's nothing to diagnose, it's an error, just treat it accordingly. You might be able to get slightly more information if you dig in to the underlying XmlHttpRequest instance that represents the request (maybe you can get the string "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"), but I don't know the details and you might be venturing into browser-dependent land.